# Django redirect is not working

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-views

```
def CompleteMini(request, mini_id):
    mini_instance = get_object_or_404(url_all, mini_address = mini_id)
    return redirect(mini_instance.full_address)
```

I have this code but it does not redirect explicitly to the URL provided as parameter. Rather it just appends the current url with this one.

Comment: it prints the required url to which it has to be redirected

Comment: but when i use redirect it goes to , for example - instead of www.foodtraingle.in it goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/ezoxaa/foodtriangle.in

Comment: Django is performing a relative redirect. You could add a scheme to make it an absolute redirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have a relative url in the `mini_instance.full_address` variable. You want to make sure it has the http:// part in it too so that it will completely redirect to the new url not try and go to it relative to the django site you are on.

Here is an example from the docs of a relative and absolute url

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')
```

This also works with full URLs:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('https://example.com/')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect